Animation is rendering correctly if there is a background but turning grey with transparent background
I am very new to blender. I am trying to animate floating embers and I followed some tutorials online.
The render works with the correct shading and colours if I have a background but if I make the background transparent (which is what I want) the render turns grey. I have tried redoing it from the tutorials I found but it still isn't working and I can't figure out why. I am not even sure where to start looking since all of the settings are the same as the tutorials.

You cannot save emission like glowing embers over a transparent background in PNG files, because the emissive pixels are added over the background, which a PNG cannot handle. Try to search for keywords like transparent emission png bloom here, there are dozens of questions here on this topic.
